# upload csv to mysql with diff date format

Tags: mysql, csv

My csv reads as follows :

```
1,01.03.13,6310086579
2,01.03.13,6310086569
3,01.03.13,6310086573
4,04.03.13,6310086592
5,04.03.13,6310086592
6,04.03.13,6310086592
7,05.03.13,6310086633
8,05.03.13,6310086639
```

I have to input the date `01.03.13` to the MySQL table as `2013-03-01`, and it's not working. like the following :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\test.csv'
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(sno, sdate, orderno, @d1) 
SET sdate = date_format(str_to_date(@d1, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: i dont know. it upload all the data, except the date column. Date is going as null. i am also bit puzzled on this.it is mysql 5.5. no warnings even occurred

Comment: Side question: Is the `sdate` column really a string datatype in the database table? Are you sure that's a good idea?

Comment: sdate is a datetime datatype.

Answer (score 0):

@d1 is always null because there are only 3 columns in your csv file. I think you meant to assign the second column in your csv file to @d1.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (sno INT,sdate DATETIME,orderno varchar(20));

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
INTO TABLE t
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(sno, @d1, orderno) 
SET sdate = date_format(str_to_date(@d1, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
;

select * from t;

+------+---------------------+-------------+
| sno  | sdate               | orderno     |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
 |   1 | 2013-03-01 00:00:00 | 6310086579
 |   2 | 2013-03-01 00:00:00 | 6310086569
 |   3 | 2013-03-01 00:00:00 | 6310086573
 |   4 | 2013-03-04 00:00:00 | 6310086592
 |   5 | 2013-03-04 00:00:00 | 6310086592
 |   6 | 2013-03-04 00:00:00 | 6310086592
 |   7 | 2013-03-05 00:00:00 | 6310086633
|    8 | 2013-03-05 00:00:00 | 6310086639  |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I don't think you need to transform column 2 at all. And you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html particularly the section starting 'User variables in the SET clause can be used in several ways'